# Optimizing SEO for User-Generated Content: Subdomain, Separate Domain, or Subdirectory?

Tags: seo, subdomain, user-generated-content

I'm developing a website which will prominently feature user-generated content. This content will be high-quality and unique, produced by the users of my paying customers. However, it's worth noting that this user content won't directly relate to the primary content of my website.

I am currently contemplating the best strategy for structuring this content from an SEO perspective. The options I'm considering are:

Setting up this content on a subdomain (e.g., username.mywebsite.com)
Hosting it on an entirely separate domain (e.g., username.mywebsite-users.com)
Placing it within a subdirectory on the main domain (e.g., mywebsite.com/username)
I'm aware that search engines like Google often treat subdomains and separate domains as distinct websites, which could potentially fragment the SEO value of my main domain. Conversely, keeping the user-generated content within a subdirectory of the main domain would allow any SEO advantages to benefit the entire domain.

Given this context, what would be the most effective approach for leveraging the SEO potential of the user-generated content?

Comment: I felt that the question was asking for opinions and that would be off-topic.  I have altered it.  Feel free to accept the change, reverse it or change it to suit.